# Limit the amount of decimal places in bc

Tags: bash, bc

I have this code

```
codonsnum=$(bc -l <<< "$lengthseq/3")
```

How can I limit the result to only 3 decimals?
The result is, for example: `2.325234985908723` and I only want 3 decimals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `scale`

```
codonsnum=$(bc -l <<< "scale=3;$lengthseq/3")
```